# Angular js - wait in method for variable change

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have scope property in my controller

```
isLoading : boolean = true;
```

and a methodA that should be executed when isLoading is false, if isLoading is true and methodA is called it should wait for isLoading to change to false and after that continue execution

```
methodA() {
   // if isLoading == true wait for it to change to false
   // then do some stuff
}
```

how can I achive this?

Comment: In javascript you should never wait. It is asynchronous. Just go on and fire an event, when isLoading changes and listen for this event. Angular uses $watch to listen to changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Use a watcher

```
$scope.$watch('isLoading', function(n){
        if(n){
            methodA();
        }
    }
)
```

**Solution 2:** If `isLoading` is bind to an `ng-model` (of an input, for instance) in some html view. Call `someotherMethod` on `ng-change` (of that input) in the html. and `someotherMethod` would be something like:

```
function someotherMethod(){
    if(isLoading){
        methodA()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use a promise object, and trigger whatever you like on
>   the response.
>
> $http returns a promise object by default so you can do some thing
>   like this:
>
> In your factory/service:

```
foo: function($http){
   return  $http({ 
                method: 'POST',
                url: API_PATH,
                data: { email: email, password: password }
           });
}
```

> Now, in your controller use it this way:

```
foo().then(
   function success(response){
      // fire your method (methodA)
   },
   function error(error){

   }
);
```